# Backup from AWS RDS to S3 bucket

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

I have 4 TB data in Aws RDS Postgres and I want to take backup in S3 bucket.What would be best strategy to take backup.

1. should I take backup Quarterly or yearly basis? What would be actual command to splits the file in quarterly/yearly in csv.gz format.
2. Tables might be in partitioned I am not sure right now.

Comment: _Why_ do you wish to create a backup in S3? How will the backup be used? The way you create the backup will depend upon how you intend to _use_ the backup.

Comment: There some analysts want to work on data and we don’t want to provide access to the rds instance that why we decide to make data available on S3.

Comment: Something that is good as a "backup" (eg SQL statements to recreate a database) is not necessarily something that can be used by analysts (who could, for example, query CSV files through Amazon Athena). Right, so the most important question is... in what format do they need the data and how will they use it? Until you have that information, you will be wasting your time creating the wrong thing.